# ERROR: column "uid" does not exist | Migrating from Oracle to Postgres

Tags: postgresql, oracle

I am currently migrating an application from an Oracle database to a PostgreSQL one. When running existing database tests in the application I came across this error:

```
ERROR: column "uid" does not exist
```

I cant find anywhere on any database forums an equivalent of Oracle's `uid` for PostgreSQL.

My question is: is there an equivalent in Postgres?

SQL is

```
select AR.* 
from V_ACC_REC_HEADLESS AR 
where AR.POSTEDDATE <= ? 
  and AR.POSTEDDATE >= ? 
  and AR.CLIENT >= ? 
  and AR.CLIENT <= ? 
  and AR.DBLACCOUNT_ID = ? - UID * 0 
  and AR.BRANCHCODE = ? 
order by AR.ACCTRANS_ID
```

Comment: What's the Original Oracle SQL? Is the context this?: https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/functions239.htm#SQLRF06153

Comment: @Philᵀᴹ yes sorry, its using the context you suggested

Comment: The code that follows that will probably not work in Postgres (what does it do with the `UID`?). You need to properly look at the application and see what it's attempting to achieve

Comment: Well, your subject line asks about _column_ "uid".  Please be aware that 'uid' is not a column name (well it shouldn't be, and given the context I don't think it even _can_ be), but rather a built-in function.

Comment: `and AR.DBLACCOUNT_ID = ? - UID * 0` can be replaced with `and AR.DBLACCOUNT_ID = ?` because the expression `uid * 0` will yield `0` and subtracting that from a number won't change that number. Does your table actually _have_ a column named `UID`?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name no there is not a listed column in the table called `UID`. Seems to be oracle database specific sql

Comment: So what does it do? Where does it come from? I have never heard of such an internal column in Oracle (but the remark about `UUID * 0` being useless, still stands)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name ill take it out

Comment: I think this question can now be closed, my problem was that oracle had some optimization, related to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26587745/sql-optimization-in-oracle)

Answer (score 0):

I'd say that the closest equivalent in PostgreSQL is the `oid` of the current user:

```
current_user::regrole::oid
```